# Login Facebook user as Wordpress user

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Sorry for the constant updating of this question! I will leave alone from now onwards.

I can register new users into my Wordpress database via a Facebook login. But I struggle to log the user into Wordpress.

It is supposed to be done via wp_signon( $credentials, $secure_cookie ), but I don't get it to log the Wordpress user into Wordpress. The user still needs to go via the Wordpress login form.

The error message I get is

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 
.../file shown below.php:36) in ..../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 680-682
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
<?php
try{
include_once "src/fbaccess.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}
try{
require_once "wp-blog-header.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}

try{
require_once "wp-includes/registration.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}

try{
require_once "wp-includes/user.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
error_log($e);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Florian's Facebook login</title>    

</head>
<body>
<!-- Copy the below code to display FB Login/Logout button -->
<?php if ($user): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>
<!-- Copy the above code to display FB Login/Logout button -->

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>You</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
   <?php $newusername = $user_profile [first_name]; ?>
<?php $newlastname = $user_profile [last_name]; ?>
   <?php $newemail    = $user_profile [email]; ?>
   <?php $newlocation = $user_profile [location]; ?>

<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

<?php
$newpassword = '1234';

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $newusername;
$creds['user_password'] = $newpassword;
if ( !empty( $remember ) ){ 
    $creds['remember'] = true;
}

$userWP = wp_signon( $creds, true );

if( is_wp_error( $userWP ) ) {
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}
else {
}
{
// Check that user doesn't already exist
if ( !username_exists($newusername) && !email_exists($newemail) )
{
// Create user and set role to subscriber

$user_id = wp_create_user( $newusername, $newpassword, $newemail);
if ( is_int($user_id) )
{
  $wp_user_object = new WP_User($user_id);
  $wp_user_object->set_role('subscriber');
  echo 'Successfully created new subscriber user.';
 }

else {
   echo 'Error with wp_create_user. No users were created.';
}
}
else {
   echo 'This user or email already exists. Nothing was done.';
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We are not going to insult you, but could you describe a little more what *don't get it to work* means? Do you have error? Unexpected results?

Comment: It doesn't login the Facebook user as a wordpress user. Meaning I still need to login via the wordpress form after having logged in to my Facebook app that creates the new user in the Wordpress database.

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert: Do my clarifications help you?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

If you login is broken you might want to check out this:

```
if ( is_wp_error($userWP) )
   echo $user->get_error_message();
```

wp_signon can ether return WP_User or WP_Error as you can see here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/user.php#L55

You might also want to take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Please post the WP_Error message and we'll find a way :)

Comment: Hi John, the error message I get with the updated code above is            Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /file above:36) in .../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 680-682

Comment: Then please do a _search_ for this error message … you are not the first person in the world encountering it.

Comment: I did search it and followed the advice I found, but without success. Could it be the structure of my file above? It is a php file, yet contains html code, too. The error is pointing at this line in the above file <?php if ($user): ?>